# Dictionary of ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, types

I'm trying to write a simple program in Java in educational purposes.
Basicly you can add students and those grades and after all collect some statistics like average students grade or filtering "good" students apart from "bad" students, etc.
After you run the application in terminal you are able to add student so: `-add <name>`, add students grade so: `-addg <name> <grade>`

So I want the application to store student names and list of those grades. The data struture is pretty simple (that is what I want now, at least it seems to be proper structure for this task. It represents simple associative array of arrays in `PHP` or dictionary of lists in `Python`):

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| String name         | ArrayList grades    |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| String anotherName  | ArrayList grades    |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

This would be coded pretty simple in `PHP` or `Python`, but in `Java` I've ran into a problem:
I just can't construct such structure:

```
$ javac StudentGrades.java
StudentGrades.java:19: variable grades might not have been initialized
                grades.add(5.0f);
                ^
Note: StudentGrades.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

`StudentGrades.java`:

```
public class StudentGrades {

    Dictionary studentGrades;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList grades;
        boolean res;
        grades.add(5.0f);
        this.studentGrades.put("Nemoden", grades);
    }
```

Could you please point me what am I doing wrong and how it should be done properly. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ArrayList grades;` you'd have to use `ArrayList grades = new ArrayList();`

Yet better:  `ArrayList<Float> grades = new ArrayList<Float>(); //or use Double or Number`

Note that unlike C or C++ creating a variable doesn't create the object as well.
In C++ you could imagine your code as `ArrayList* grades;` i.e. you'd just create the reference/pointer here.

Additional thoughts:

1. `Dictionary studentGrades;` this will be initialized to null.
2. `public void main(String[] args)` that's not a valid main function since it would have to be static
3. if you have a `public static void main(String[] args)` you can't use `this` since you don't have an object instance in the static context
4. You can't instantiate `Dictionary` since it is abstract. Use one of its subclasses, e.g. `new Hashtable<String, List<Float>>()`, or a map, e.g. `Map<String, List<Float> dictionary = new HashMap<String, List<Float>>();`
5. Note that local primitive variables are also not initialized, so this could give you an error too: `boolean res;` In Java only class members are initialized, local variables are not.

Comment: Snap! I tried to use `ArrayList<float>` (in lowercase) and compiler did not let me do that cause it expected a reference but not a primitive type declaration. All of a sudden there is a reference for `float` :)

Comment: You can't use primitives but have to use objects. Note that I mentioned uppercase Float.

Comment: @Thomas: actually, you can use primitives, provided that you are using Java 6.

Comment: @Pablo Really? Didn't find that in the spec so far, but maybe I overlooked it. Can you point me to the corresponding portion of the spec?

Comment: @Thomas: nevermind. I was **completely** wrong. Sorry. You can add primitives though. And they are auto-boxed to Object types...

Comment: @Pablo Yes, that's why I didn't comment on `grades.add(5.0f);`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your variable:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList grades = new ArrayList();
    boolean res;
    grades.add(5.0f);
    this.studentGrades.put("Nemoden", grades);
}
```

Also, if you are planning to use `studentGrades` on a static context, that variable **must** be static also:

```
static Dictionary studentGrades;
```

Since you are trying Java for educational purposes, I would strongly recommend to start by learning basic concepts (classes, visibility, constructors, member, variables) and then going for concepts like Collections, arrays and the API in general. Also, do consider using collections along with generics.

To iterate your dictionary:

```
for (Object key : studentGrades.keySet()) {
    Object value = studentGrades.get(key);
    // do something with key & value
}
```

Comment: And how do I iterate over a `Dictionary` in Java? As I see, you are a Python programmer, so "`pythonically-speaking`" I want to do something like this: `for (name, grades) in studentGrades.items(): avg = sum(grades) / len(grades); if avg < 1.0: print "%s is a dumb (hes score is %f)" % (name, avg)`

Comment: @Pablo that's no valid Java, you'd need to change that to `for (Object key : studentGrades.keySet())`.

Comment: @Thomas I've confused him with `Python` i think :)

Comment: @Thoma: true. Thanks. Going back and forth to C# confuses me. As it did with the Generics+Primitives stuff...

Comment: Thank you a lot: you helped me to figure things out. Hard to decide whos answer to accept (both clarifying and highlighting what is wrong and educational). But, just want to add some reputation for @Thomas. Hope, it's okay.